# Aligning JLabels in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, boxlayout

I've been searching around for days trying to find the answer to this, and I can't find out what's wrong. What I want to do is make it so the top JLabel (called `display`) align to the right and the bottom JLabel (called `notice`) to align to the left. Neither seems to want to do either. From what I've read, what I have should work, but it doesn't. Help?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Calculator {

    private static JButton clear, add, subtract, multiply, divide, equals, point, zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine;
    private static JLabel display, notice, blank1, blank2, blank3;
    private static JPanel mainPanel, buttonPanel, topLabel, bottomLabel;

    public static void goGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
        mainPanel.setBorder(empty);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,4, 5,5));
        Border buttonBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,0,10,0);
        buttonPanel.setBorder(buttonBorder);

        topLabel = new JPanel();
        bottomLabel = new JPanel();

        clear = new JButton("C");
        add = new JButton("+");
        subtract = new JButton("-");
        multiply = new JButton("*");
        divide = new JButton("/");
        equals = new JButton("=");
        point = new JButton(".");
        zero = new JButton("0");
        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");

        // Here I added ActionListeners to all the buttons...

        display = new JLabel("0");
        display.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        notice = new JLabel("*Maximum 19 digits - Order of operations not taken into account*");
        notice.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        blank1 = new JLabel();
        blank2 = new JLabel();
        blank3 = new JLabel();

        buttonPanel.add(clear);
        buttonPanel.add(blank1);
        buttonPanel.add(blank2);
        buttonPanel.add(blank3);
        buttonPanel.add(seven);
        buttonPanel.add(eight);
        buttonPanel.add(nine);
        buttonPanel.add(divide);
        buttonPanel.add(four);
        buttonPanel.add(five);
        buttonPanel.add(six);
        buttonPanel.add(multiply);
        buttonPanel.add(one);
        buttonPanel.add(two);
        buttonPanel.add(three);
        buttonPanel.add(subtract);
        buttonPanel.add(zero);
        buttonPanel.add(point);
        buttonPanel.add(equals);
        buttonPanel.add(add);

        topLabel.add(display);
        bottomLabel.add(notice);

        mainPanel.add(topLabel);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        mainPanel.add(bottomLabel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    } //end goGUI

    //ActionListener classes went here...

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Set cross-platform Java L&F (also called "Metal")
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {}

        goGUI();

    } //end main
} //end Calculator
```

I removed all ActionListener stuff for clarity. But this is the layout that I can't fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider having topLabel not use the default FlowLayout but rather something that makes its contents fill it up such as BorderLayout.

```
topLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Next make sure that you set the display's horizontal alignment, not its alignmentX to the right:

```
display.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

Similar changes should be made for your notice JLabel and its container.

Comment: +1 for the working solution! Is there a difference between `topLabel.add(display, BorderLayout.EAST);` and `display.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);`? In this case it's the same result.

Comment: @alain: yes there's a big difference. If you add it BorderLayout.EAST the JLabel doesn't expand. Put a border around the label to see the difference.

Answer (score 4):

I add few line of code because I like BoxLayout. I have almost the same problems in align components few hours ago.

If we want to acheive something like this

```
//  +----------------------------------+
//  |  Label1  |            |  Label2  |
//  +----------------------------------+
```

You have only to put a "Box.createHorizontalGlue()" between the two.

If instead we want something like this:

```
//  +----------------------------------+
//  |  Label1  |                       |
//  |----------+            +----------|
//  |                       |  Label2  |
//  +----------------------------------+
```

We have to put the labels inside two differen JPanel, setting a different AlignmentX to them.
This is because in the layout all the components should have the same alignmentX. To avoid this restriction we can do something like this:

```
//  +-----------------------------------------+
//  |  Label1  |   label1 is inside a JPanel  |
//  +----------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+
//  + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+----------+
//  |  label2 also                 |  Label2  |
//  +-----------------------------------------+
```

(don't mind about the space between the two panel, is only for graphic)
This can be done with this code:

```
mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Label1");
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setOpaque(false);
p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
p1.add(lbl1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Label1");
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
p2.setOpaque(false);
p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
p2.add(lbl2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

mainPanel.add(p1);
mainPanel.add(p2);
```

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `BorderLayout()` :

```
public static void goGUI() {

        ....

        topLabel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        bottomLabel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        ....

        topLabel.add(display, BorderLayout.EAST);
        bottomLabel.add(notice, BorderLayout.WEST);


    }
```

Also remove these calls :

```
 display.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
 notice.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```